# How to get wordpress menu in my application

Tags: php, wordpress

I have website on WP, and within this website I have my own application written on PHP at /my_app

And I want to load Wordpress menu within this application, how I can do it without hacks like iframe, ajax, etc, without database querying. Maximally using wordpress code!

Answer (score 0):

It is simple just connect WordPress database from your app and fetch menu using custom query.

Comment: This is bad Idea, I think, what if i have big tree menu with big amount of nested sub-menus? Will be this litle query?